# Unable to create a constant value of type 'WebApplication13.Models.Service'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6, asp.net-core-mvc

i am trying to convert a project from ASP.NET CORE to ASP.NET MVC 4.6.1,
And i am having an issue with a linq when i try to get some data from db.

Here's the code from Asp.Net Core

```
public IEnumerable<UserOperators> GetSkillAgents(List<Models.Services> skillsList)
{
    return _context.UserOperators.Include(p => p.GroupOperators)
        .Where(p => p.GroupOperators.Any(o => o.GuidGroup == Guid.Parse("11111111-1111-1111-1111-000000000004")))
        .Include(p => p.Lines).Where(p => p.Lines.Any(o => o.ServicesLines.Any(a => skillsList.Any(s => s.GuidService == a.GuidService))));
}
```

And heres the code i made for Asp.Net MVC 4.6.1

```
public IEnumerable<UserOperator> GetSkillAgents(List<Service> skillsList)
{
    var guid = Guid.Parse("11111111-1111-1111-1111-000000000004");
    return _context.UserOperators.Where(p => p.GroupOperators.Any(o => o.guidGroup == guid))
       .Where(p => p.Lines.Any(o => o.Services_Lines.Any(a => skillsList.Any(s => s.guidService == a.guidService))));
    }
```

this throwns an error :

> Unable to create a constant value of type 'WebApplication13.Models.Service'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.**

I found some answers and tried adding `.AsEnumerable()`, it works perferct and does not throw any error but the query takes so long to execute and return datas (like 3-4 seconds more than in ASP.NET CORE).

```
return _context.UserOperators.Where(p => p.GroupOperators
    .Any(o => o.guidGroup == guid)).AsEnumerable()
    .Where(p => p.Lines.Any(o => o.Services_Lines.Any(a => skillsList.Any(s => s.guidService == a.guidService))));
```

So basically what i need from this query is to return me that user if the Service_Lines list and skillsList has any same item (guidService).

This is the query linq makes for sql

```
"SELECT \r\n    [Extent1].[guidUserOperator] AS [guidUserOperator], 
\r\n    [Extent1].[Number] AS [Number], 
\r\n    [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
\r\n    [Extent1].[strAccountName] AS [strAccountName],
 \r\n    [Extent1].[strRemotePwd] AS [strRemotePwd], 
\r\n    [Extent1].[guidServiceForCallingNr] AS [guidServiceForCallingNr], 
\r\n    [Extent1].[nSuppressCallingNr] AS [nSuppressCallingNr], 
\r\n    [Extent1].[DynamOpPhoneNr] AS [DynamOpPhoneNr], 
\r\n    [Extent1].[guidDynamOpMandant] AS [guidDynamOpMandant], 
\r\n    [Extent1].[dtDisableBefore] AS [dtDisableBefore], 
\r\n    [Extent1].[dtDisableAfter] AS [dtDisableAfter], 
\r\n    [Extent1].[recordingIn] AS [recordingIn], 
\r\n    [Extent1].[guidSecurityGroup] AS [guidSecurityGroup], 
\r\n    [Extent1].[strMailbox] AS [strMailbox], 
\r\n    [Extent1].[nAlwaysSendMessageToEmail] AS [nAlwaysSendMessageToEmail],
 \r\n    [Extent1].[strSMS] AS [strSMS], 
\r\n    [Extent1].[recordingOut] AS [recordingOut], 
\r\n    [Extent1].[guidServiceForCallingNrOutbound] AS [guidServiceForCallingNrOutbound], 
\r\n    [Extent1].[LoginWithOffHookMode] AS [LoginWithOffHookMode], 
\r\n    [Extent1].[LogoutCallAction] AS [LogoutCallAction], 
\r\n    [Extent1].[OffHookMode] AS [OffHookMode], 
\r\n    [Extent1].[StatusMessage] AS [StatusMessage], 
\r\n    [Extent1].[PreferAcceptByCTI] AS [PreferAcceptByCTI], 
\r\n    [Extent1].[ExternalId] AS [ExternalId], 
\r\n    [Extent1].[EnableAdministrativeRecording] AS [EnableAdministrativeRecording],
 \r\n    [Extent1].[Surname] AS [Surname],
 \r\n    [Extent1].[RingingTimeoutAction] AS [RingingTimeoutAction], 
\r\n    [Extent1].[Pin] AS [Pin]
\r\n    FROM [dbo].[UserOperators] AS [Extent1]\r\n    
        WHERE ( EXISTS (SELECT 
\r\n        1 AS [C1]
\r\n        FROM [dbo].[GroupOperators] AS [Extent2]
\r\n        WHERE ([Extent1].[guidUserOperator] = [Extent2].[guidUserOperator]) 
        AND ([Extent2].[guidGroup] = @p__linq__0)
\r\n    )) AND ( EXISTS (SELECT 
\r\n        1 AS [C1]
\r\n        FROM ( SELECT 
\r\n            [Extent3].[guidLine] AS [guidLine]
\r\n            FROM [dbo].[Lines] AS [Extent3]
\r\n            WHERE [Extent1].[guidUserOperator] = [Extent3].[guidOwnerAgent]
\r\n        )  AS [Project2]
\r\n        WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 
\r\n            1 AS [C1]
\r\n            FROM ( SELECT 
\r\n                [Extent4].[guidService] AS [guidService]
\r\n                FROM [dbo].[Services_Lines] AS [Extent4]
\r\n                WHERE [Project2].[guidLine] = [Extent4].[guidLine]
\r\n            )  AS [Project3]
\r\n            WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 
\r\n                1 AS [C1]
\r\n                FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable1]
\r\n                WHERE 1 = 0
\r\n            )
\r\n        )
\r\n    ))"
```

Comment: Have you tried using `skillsList.Contains( )` instead of .Any()?

Comment: @DylanNicholson how can i do that since skillsList is a list of Services Model and Services_Lines is a list of Services_Lines Model. All they have in common is that both have a guidService variable.

Comment: Sure, so first create a list that is just the GUIDs, then use Contains on that.

Comment: Like @DylanNicholson said, but make sure to put the `Guid`s enumerable in a variable outside the query. There are many similar questions on SO.

Comment: I have to say I am curious why there'd be a difference between ASP.NET core and ASP.NET 4.6 on this one.

Comment: @DylanNicholson i just tried but it takes so long to execute, like 3-4 seconds more than in ASP.NET CORE

Comment: @IvanStoev i just tried but it takes so long to execute, like 3-4 seconds more than in ASP.NET CORE

Comment: @DylanNicholson i dont know, first of all in asp.net 4.6 you cannot add that Guid.Parse() inside linq, and also i couldnt use Include() as in Asp.net Core

Comment: Ertan are you able to determine the SQL query being generated? (the returned IQueryable< > exposes it via .ToString() usually).

Comment: @DylanNicholson just added to question, since there is a lot of code in it.

Comment: Hmm, that's an odd query - `WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT   1 AS [C1]
    FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable1]
 WHERE 1 = 0
         )` would seem guaranteed to always be false...but it doesn't really explain why it would take 3-4 seconds (assuming there's not massive amounts of data and you have sensible indexes).

Comment: @DylanNicholson yep theres not massive amounts data at all.All the tables that are part of this query has maximum of 100 rows.

Comment: Then I'd say your delay is not due to the way your query is written.

Comment: @DylanNicholson so what do you think that could be the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I can't test it, but give this a go:

```
    public IEnumerable<UserOperator> GetSkillAgents(List<Service> skillsList)
    {
        var guid = "11111111-1111-1111-1111-000000000004";

        from userOperator in _context.UserOperators
        from groupOperator in userOperator.GroupOperators
        from line in userOperator.Lines
        from services_Line in line.Services_Lines
        from skill in skillsList
        where groupOperator.guidGroup.ToString() == guid &&
              skill.guidService == services_Line.guidService
        select userOperator;
    }
```

**EDIT** Now, we're comparing strings with strings.

Comment: In that case, it's likely that the problem is with the fact that you're passing a `Guid` to the `where` clause. Try just passing the `string` `Guid` you have without parsing it.

Comment: That doesnt work since groupOperator is Guid and it thorws an error trying to see if an guid is equals to string